# Tab Bar disappears on segue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, segue

[image: Storyboard]

**What I want to achieve:**

- I have a `"Login" ViewController` which segues to a `Tab Bar Controller`.
- My `Tab Bar Controller` goes to a `Navigation Controller` and then `"Home" ViewController` with a `Table View`. This view is my "Home/Welcome" page. I want there to be a Tab Bar at the bottom as well as a static table which I can edit with Prototype Cells. Each cell goes to a different `ViewController`.
- Then, I want to be able to tap each Cell (I have "Info" setup for now) and it segue to the corresponding `ViewController`. For now, the "Info" cell should go to the second `Navigation Controller` and then `"Information" ViewController`.
- From there, I want another static table which I can edit with Prototype Cells. Each cell will go to a seperate stack of ViewControllers.

**My problem:**
When I segue from the "Info" cell in the `"Home" ViewController`, the Information tab bar "pushes" up, and the Tab Bar disappears. I've experimented with other segue forms but none of them maintain the Tab Bar. 
I want it so you can use either the Tab Bar to navigate to the Info ViewController or the cell on the Home/Welcome ViewController to navigate to the Info page.

*I have no code at all at this point, I am just using these segues.*
Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve what I want to achieve, and if so, provide as much sample code as I'm extremely new to Swift.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: things are not visible in the screen shared by you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add `segue` to open the `"Information" ViewController` which is part of `UITabBarController`.

You must have used `didSelectRowAt` for cell selection in `tableview`. Just add one line in it as it is :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true) {
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
}
```

This will change the tab and open the `"Information" ViewController`.

If you want to load the `"Information" ViewController` with data relevant to cell selection you can go with `Protocols` or `NotificationCentre` which can pass data to `"Information" ViewController` from `Homeviewcontroller` on cell selection.

Comment: Thank you for this, would you be able to explain to me how to make that function you provided work? Is there anything I need to do or can I use that code as-it-is?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: I tried putting this in my `HomeViewController.swift` file like this:

`import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true) {
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
    }
}

}`
...but I get an error "Extra argument 'animated ' in call on line 9

Comment: why an extra `{}`, change this `{ self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1 }` to ` self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1 `.

Comment: That seemed to fix it, but then I got an error in the console when I went to navigate to the HomeViewController: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Light___Sound_App.HomeViewController 0x7f99bfe21e90> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key staticDataSource.'`

Comment: have you got any suggestions? I need this app done ASAP so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I hope you have removed the segue from Home/Welcome VC to Information VC navigation controller. For the error you commented please check this : https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/52021/how-do-i-fix-the-issue-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key-in-xcode-6/